# entropy and histogram

Tags: matlab, image-processing, entropy

I try to read a file from my workspace,and to calculate the entropy of order one of each image band using the histogram of the gray levels
this is my try and I'am enable to read the .mat file with the load function

```
clc
I = load('file.mat'); 
E = entropy(I);
hist(E);
figure
plot(E);
```

Update:
this is the code:

```
I = load('file.mat'); 
E = zeros(1,size(I,3));

for idx = 1 : size(I,3)
    %// Calculate PDF
    chan = I(:,:,idx);
    h = imhist(chan);

end
```

Now,I get this error:
[image]

thanks again for any help

Comment: What exactly is `I`?  Is this a colour image?  It's not very clear from your code.  BTW, `entropy` **already** computes the entropy of the entire image.  It internally computes the histogram / PDF of intensities and computes the entropy that way.  Also, take a look at this post for insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726735/how-to-calculate-the-shannon-entropy-of-a-part-of-image-data/27726789#27726789 - However, this post is only calculating the entropy for a portion of the image.  Just change the code so that it uses it over the entire image instead.

Comment: I is .mat file in which I should calculate the entropy using an histogram

Comment: I don't know How can I extract information from the mat file calculate the entropy than display the result in an histogram

Comment: **What exactly is `I`**?

Comment: it's a variable I used to load in it the file Indian_pines_corrected.mat

Comment: I thought that is the same thing like to load color images(png,jpg,..)

Comment: Is `I` a colour image?  You haven't answered my question.  We can't help you if you keep avoiding the answers to our questions for clarification.  If you don't answer these, I can't and won't help you.

Comment: sorry,yes it's a color image

Comment: So you wish to calculate the entropy per colour channel?  Are you allowed to use the `entropy` command, or do you have to do this by yourself from first principles?

Comment: I used the entropy command just to test ,but I didn't test it from basic principales with matlab :)

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Are you seeking to calculate this from first principles, or can you use the `entropy` command?

Comment: yes I'am looking to calculate this from first principles

Comment: Thank you for answering all of my questions (finally).  I'll write an answer.

Comment: ok thanks and sorry,I'am a biginner in matlab and I find it difficult to do this

Comment: That's no problem at all.  I just wanted to get all of the facts before I answered your question.  I've written an answer for you.  Good luck!

Comment: It's saying that your `I` is a `struct` and not an image. You probably used `save` to save your workspace. Please type in `I` into the command prompt, push ENTER, and copy and paste its output here.

Comment: hello rayryeng sorry for late this is the I: I = 

    indian_pines_corrected: [145x145x200 double]

Comment: Uh huh.  That's what I thought.  `I` is a **`struct`**.  Therefore, you need to access the actual image data by doing: `im = I.indians_pines_corrected;`.  I have corrected my post.  Check it now - it should work.  BTW, it would help if you didn't give us the wrong information.  `I` is not an image - it is a `struct`.

Comment: thanks for help and sorry for the mistake,it was a school task and our teacher said that is a color image,whenever thanks again fir help ^_^

Comment: another question pleaze why the result is a zeros

Comment: That's probably your image. That isn't anything to do with the code I wrote. I can't help you with that unfortunately! Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall from definition that the entropy (Shannon) is defined as:

[image]

In this case, `b = 2`.  What you need to do is assuming we have a grayscale image, we need to find the probability distribution function of the image, then use the above definition to calculate our entropy.  The [`entropy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/entropy.html) command in MATLAB already does this for us, but from your comments, you want to do this from first principles.  Just follow the procedure I outlined above.  As such, for a grayscale image, we first need to grab the histogram of the image through [`imhist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html), then normalize this by the total number of pixels in your image to get the probability distribution function.

Therefore, if your image is loaded into `im` and is grayscale, this is how you calculate the entropy:

```
%// Grab image data
im = I.indian_pines_corrected;

%// Calculate PDF
h = imhist(I);
h = h / numel(I);

%// Set any entries in the PDF that are 0 to 1 so log calculation works
h(h == 0) = 1;

%// Calculate entropy
E = -sum(h.*log2(h));
```

---

The above code goes through the logic we have outlined.  However, look at the third line of code.  Any entries in the probability distribution function that are 0, the `log` calculation would generate an invalid number, so in order for the `log` function to safely make this 0, we set any values in the PDF that are 0 to 1, so that `log(1) = 0`.  Essentially, the entropy calculation will ignore these entries so that we can properly calculate the value.

Because you have a **colour** image, all you have to do is treat each colour channel as a separate grayscale image, so we can just use the above code and loop over each channel.  Just extract each colour channel as a grayscale image, and calculate the entropy of each colour channel.  Therefore, assuming `I` is a colour image:

```
%// Grab image data
im = I.indian_pines_corrected;

E = zeros(1,size(I,3));

for idx = 1 : size(I,3)
    %// Calculate PDF
    chan = I(:,:,idx);
    h = imhist(chan);
    h = h / numel(chan);

    %// Find any entries in the PDF that are 0 to 1 so log calculation works
    h(h == 0) = 1;

    %// Calculate entropy
    E(idx) = -sum(h.*log2(h));
end
```

`E` would be an array where each element would tell you the entropy for each colour channel.  Therefore, the first element would be the entropy for the first channel (red), the second element would be the second (green), and so on.

Comment: thanks rayryeng for Help but now I'am facing a new problem,I have updated the post

Comment: @Lina - Please don't edit my post.  Your changes would have broken my code and it wouldn't have worked.  In the future, if you want to suggest changes to a post, leave a comment and verify that your proposed change will work and it is giving the same message as it was before your proposed edit.